# Start Quicken from Scratch

Tags: accounts

I want to start over with all my accounts without any historical information. I have been using it for 9 years and do not want to see all the history although I'd like to have it accessible if needed. I just want to start clean again. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your version of Quicken, but in mine under the File menu there is an option "New Quicken File".  I won't try it myself since I don't want to start over, but according to various web pages (e.g., [this one](https://www.quicken.com/support/how-do-i-create-new-quicken-data-file)) you can use this to create a new clean data file that you can use going forward.

I'm not sure what you mean by "start over with all my accounts".  Doing what I described above will create a totally blank Quicken file, in which you'll have to add your accounts.  I'm not aware of a way to erase or hide the history while keeping the same accounts.